# Is this a valid way to make a custom type thread safe? And general threading questions

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a few general questions when dealing with threads. I have been looking around but haven't really seen any answers to my questions

When dealing with multiple variables in a class you want to be thread safe, are you supposed to have one "lock object" for every variable you want to lock in the class? Like this?

```
static readonly object lockForVarA = new object();
private float varA;

static readonly object lockForVarB = new object();
private float varB;
```

Also is this a valid way to handle thread safing a custom type?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
       //Do some kind of work IE load an assembly
    }
}


public class SomeOtherClass : BaseClassFiringFromRandomThread
{
    static readonly object someClassLock = new object();
    SomeClass someClass;
    public override void Init()//this is fired from any available thread, can be fired multiple times and even at the same time
    {
        lock(someClassLock)
        {
            if(someClass == null)
                someClass = new SomeClass();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is in the constructor of a class that can be called from any thread at any time

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question. If you have two questions, **post two questions**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When dealing with multiple variables in a class you want to be thread safe, are you supposed to have one "lock object" for every variable you want to lock in the class?

There are two rules:

- Be "fine grained". Have as many locks as possible, one for each variable. Access the variable under its lock every time you use it.  Lock as little code as possible to ensure scalability.  If you forget to lock a variable, you'll cause a race condition, and if you get the lock ordering wrong, you'll cause a deadlock, so make sure you get it perfect.
- Be "coarse-grained".  Have just one lock, and put all the critical sections under that lock. Having many locks decreases contention but increases the chance of deadlocks and other errors, so have as few locks as possible, with as much code as possible in each.  Of course, this also increases the risk of deadlocks since now there is lots more code inside the locks that can have inversions, and it decreases scalability.

As you have no doubt noticed, the standard advice is completely contradictory.  That's because locks are terrible.

My advice: **if you don't share variables across threads then you don't need to have any locks at all**.

> Also is this a valid way to handle thread safing a custom type?

The code looks reasonable so far, but if your intention is to lazy-load some logic then **do not write your own threading logic**. Just use `Lazy<T>` and make it do the work. It was written by experts.

**Always use the highest-level tool designed by experts that is available to you**.  Rolling your own threading primitives is a recipe for disaster.

Whatever you do **do not take the advice in the other answer that says you must use double checked locking**. There are no circumstances in which you **must** use double-checked locking. Single checked locking is safer, easier, and more likely to be correct.  Only use double-checked locking when (1) you have overwhelming empirical evidence that contention is the cause of a measurable, user-impacting performance problem that will be fixed by going low-lock, and (2) you can explain what rules in the C# memory model make double checked locking safe.

If you can't do (1) then you have no reason to do double checked locking, and if you can't do (2), you can't do it with any confidence of safety.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a [double checked lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern. There isn't need to acquire your someClassLock lock once someClass has been initialised, and locking it there will just cause unnecessary contention.

```
if (someClass == null)
{
    lock(someClassLock)
    {
        if (someClass == null)
            someClass = new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

You need the inner if block because it is possible a concurrent thread may have created someClass after the first null check but before your lock was acquired.

Of course, you need to also ensure that SomeClass is written in a way that is itself threadsafe, but this will safely ensure that only one instance of someClass is created.

An alternative method is to use `Lazy<T>` with a suitable `LazyThreadSafetyMode`.

Comment: Do not use the double checked locking pattern, or any low-lock pattern, unless two conditions are true: (1) You have a demonstrated performance problem which justifies a low-lock technique, and (2) you can explain in detail what rules of the C# memory model justify that the double-checked locking pattern is safe.

Comment: @EricLippert, fair call. I didn't notice the missing volatile keyword. Is that your main concern here? OK, answering my question here, someClass may become not null during the new SomeClass operation. That's bad obviously. Can it be made safe my assigning it to a temporary local variable first?

Comment: OK, pop quiz. **Does the C# memory model require volatile in your scenario**?  If yes, why? What's the condition that can make the code incorrect, and on what operating systems can it be observed? If no, precisely what rules make the non-volatile reads guaranteed to be up-to-date?  Extra bonus: does the fact that C# guarantees that constructor calls are special effects matter, or could there be any non-constructor code in there and it doesn't matter?

Comment: Super extra bonus: suppose we modify your code to `if (!init) lock(classLock) if (!init) { someClass = new...; init = true; }`  for boolean `init`. Neither is volatile. **Is this a guaranteed correct implementation of double checked locking**?  Why or why not?

Comment: OK, I am just trying to understand this because I have inherited code that implements it and I want to understand my risks here. My personal preference was and is Lazy<T> which is I guess the take home message. I will retract my answer shortly so there is no confusion for others who stumble upon it, but I just wanted to get my head around this. My understanding of volatile is that it tells the compiler to not reorder instructions or cache them so that multiple threads see the impact of the assignments immediately. So it would be needed in x86/windows for sure.

Comment: Volatile absolutely does NOT ensure that multiple threads see assignments immediately!  ABSOLUTELY NOT.  If you believe that then you believe a falsehood.  **Volatile introduces acquire and release semantics on variables.**  There is no requirement whatsoever that volatile accesses are published immediately to other threads, and indeed, **there is no requirement that multiple threads agree on a single consistent ordering of reads and writes**.

Comment: As I always do when I find someone who doesn't understand volatile, I give them this puzzle: https://web.archive.org/web/20160304015511/http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/  -- here we have a program where every variable is volatile, all accesses but one are under locks, and we are on the strong x86 memory model and *still* there is a race condition that can produce a surprising result.

Comment: Poorly chosen words by me. I don't mean to imply that the values are pushed to other threads. I mean that they aren't allowed to be cached in the registers so that if another thread chooses to read that, they must read from memory rather than the register they may have otherwise cached it in. For super extra bonus, I would say not correct because there is no guarantee that another thread sees the result of init = true; from your thread when they are doing if(!init) and therefore you may end up constructing two objects.

Comment: Caching in registers isn't the only problem. It's *cache lines* that are the problem! Cache lines introduce scenarios in which reads are moved backwards in time and writes are moved into the future.

Comment: No, the problem is not that you end up constructing two objects. By the time you enter the lock for the second time, you've crossed the memory barrier of leaving the lock for the first time, and the memory barrier of entering it for the second time, so `init` is `true` by the time you get inside the lock the second time. The code is still wrong though; what's the real scenario where it is broken?

Comment: Well I have some lite reading for this evening. I am guessing here that your init=true line might arrive ahead of the someClass=new ... line due to your cache lines.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. The init=true can arrive on one thread before the assignment to someclass, and then someclass can be read to be null after skipping the initialization. There is no memory barrier that prevents this because **we don't enter the lock if init is observed to be true!** These are the nightmare scenarios you have to live with when you decide that taking the few hundred ns it takes to enter an uncontested lock is *just too expensive*.

Comment: In that scenario, making `init` volatile solves the problem. As does introducing a memory barrier explicitly, or making the outer read of init volatile. Or, the whole problem could be avoided by (1) single checked locking, or (2) **don't share memory on multiple threads**.

Comment: Summing up: people think volatile means "no caching in registers". They think it means "always go back to main memory". It means neither. Rather, we define an "effect" as any write, a volatile read, or a throw, and a "critical point" as a volatile read or write, a thread start or stop, or a lock.  **Effects are guaranteed to be observed at critical points**. Moreover: **a volatile read cannot be moved forwards in time, and a volatile write cannot be moved backwards in time.**

Comment: So, for example: reads can be moved backwards, but a read inside a lock will never be observed to move backwards to before the lock. Similarly, writes can be moved forwards, but a write in a lock is never observed to move forwards past the end of the lock. But there is no requirement whatsoever that a volatile read never be observed to be moved backwards in time with respect to a volatile write *of a different variable*, and in fact this can be observed to happen.

Comment: If you find all this confusing, I do too! That's why I never, ever write low-lock code.